# Selecting default value of option as a model in angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a cafe model which I want to show as default value from cafe list. Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="theme" style="margin-top: 20px;">Cafe Name</label>
    <select class="form-control" [ngModel]="cafeList" (ngModelChange)="changeCafe($event)" name="cafe">
        <option *ngFor="let cafe of cafeList" [ngValue]="cafe">{{cafe.name}}</option>
    </select>

    <a href="" style="margin-top: 10px;"  [routerLink]="['/cafe/edit-cafe', selectedCafe.cafeId]" class="btn btn-warning">
        <i class="ti-comment pdd-right-5"></i>
        <span>View Cafe</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

For retrieving data I am doing something like this

```
const data   = d[0];
this.ad =  <AdsItem> data.payload.val();
this.selectedCafe = this.ad.cafe;
this.cafeId = this.ad.cafe.cafeId;

this.subscription = this.db.list<CafeItem>('cafeList').snapshotChanges().subscribe(d=>{          
    this.cafeList = [];
    d.forEach(data =>{
        var user =  <CafeItem> data.payload.val();
        this.cafeList.push(user);
    });           
});
```

Now I am not exactly sure how can I set the selectedCafe as default Cafe

Comment: `ngModel` should be a string not array

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems

1. Your `ngModel`  should be a string not list on the selection process angular will change that string to your option value
2. `[ngValue]="cafe"` binding object as a value is invalid, because browser will render it as `ng-reflect-ng-value="[object Object]"`

Change your selection code to this:

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="cafeModel" (ngModelChange)="changeCafe($event)" name="cafe">
        <option *ngFor="let cafe of cafeList" [ngValue]="cafe.name">{{cafe.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

and in typescript assign `cafeModel` defaultvalue

here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vglnz1)

Answer (score 0):

Use ngModel inside select tag with single value to display the default value and it will also update the selectedCafe variable whenever you change the option since it's two way binding.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCafe"(ngModelChange)="changeCafe($event)" name="cafe">
        <option *ngFor="let cafe of cafeList" [ngValue]="cafe">{{cafe.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> `<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCafe" name="cafe" style="width: 250px"> <option *ngFor="let cafe of cafeList" [ngValue]="cafe">{{ cafe }}</option> </select>`

---

.ts File: 
cafeList = [1, 2, 3, 4];
selectedCafe = 2;

Please Modify your code accordingly, hope this helps.